# Jquery How to wait indexedDB to read from stored object and put it in backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, indexeddb

I have this jquery function:

```
fillCities: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.indexedDB("xyz").objectStore("cities").each(function (elem) {
                   var act = elem.value;
                   self.cities.push(act);
            });
        },
```

I want to wait till it fills all elements into cities then call `render();`
Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the jquery-indexeddb [plugin](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb). If so, `$.indexedDB` returns a promise, so you can wait to call your `render` function accordingly:

```
fillCities: function () {
  var self = this;
  var promise = $.indexedDB('xyz').objectStore('cities').each(function(elem) {
    var act = elem.value;
    self.cities.push(act);
  });

  promise.done(function() {
    view.render();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much i read about deferred and promise but didn't know how to use it...now i knew:):):):)